# What does class="h-disabled" mean?

Tags: html

class="h-disabled"

I've come across this code testing out website links, can anyone tell me what it means?

Comment: That is just an HTML class attribute, which is usually effected by CSS.

Answer (score 1):

That is a [class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-class-attribute/) attribute.  By itself, it does nothing.  The h-disabled is just a name for the class.  Using CSS you can style that section by name.  It can also be used by javascript to identify that section of the html to perform actions on.

Comment: It's a class attribute, not a tag.

Comment: @StackSlave Good catch.